# How to adjust this bash script to run telnet commands successfully while being in SSH?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, telnet, zebra-printers

I am attempting to write a bash script that will do the following work flow:

1. Telnet into networked device via IP address on port 9100 `telnet x.x.x.x 9100`
2. Run SGD command `! U1 getvar \"internal_wired.ip.timeout.value\"`.
3. Expect output value of `"10"`.

Here is the bash script I've written so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=(x.x.x.x) 


    for i in ${IP}
    do
      echo " "
      echo "Welcome! This script will check the timeout value of this networked device."
      echo "The expected output should be `"10`". Let's get started!!"
      echo " "
      sleep 4
      echo "5....."
      sleep 1
      echo "4...."
      sleep 1
      echo "3..."
      sleep 1
      echo "2.."
      sleep 1
      echo "1."
      sleep 1
      echo " "
      telnet ${i} 9100 << END_SSH
        sleep 5
        getvar \"internal_wired.ip.timeout.value\"
        sleep 5
    END_SSH
    done
```

When I run this script via `bash mycode.sh`, I get the following output in Terminal.app:

```
$ bash mycode.sh 

Welcome! This script will check the timeout value of this networked device.
The expected output should be "10". Let's get started!!

5.....
4....
3...
2..
1.

Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to x.x.x.x.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
[user@server ~]$
```

`x.x.x.x` is an IP placeholder just to add.

In theory, after the `Escape character is '^]'.` line, the script should have ran the `! U1 getvar "internal_wired.ip.timeout.value\"` command.

Also, we should have had an expected output of `"10"`.

When I first wrote this script, I initially did not have the `END_SSH` command in it. A colleague introduced that to me and said to wrap the `telnet` commands in the `END_SSH` because of how Terminal technically jumps out of SSH when you are in telnet. I've tried utilizing `END_SSH`, but am not successful.

How do I get the telnet command to run successfully and get the expected output value?

Comment: Look into `expect`.

Comment: `expect` is a ridiculous overkill for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what "END_SSH" is. It's not a "command" - it's what's called "Here-document" in bash.

Essentially the text between the `<<END_SSH` and the `END_SSH` is a "here-document" that is piped into stdin of `telnet ${i} 9100`. So, the `sleep 5` commands are never actually executed and the input reaches EOF before the connection is even established.

I don't know what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but I would guess that the following will work better. Oh, and what's with that weird `IP=(x.x.x.x)` declaration? Is that supposed to be an array?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a IP=(1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 4.4.4.4)

for i in "${IP[@]}"; do
    echo " "
    echo "Welcome! This script will check the timeout value of this networked device."
    echo "The expected output should be \"10\". Let's get started!!"
    sleep 4
    for j in {5..1}; do
        echo $j
        sleep 1
    done

    { sleep 5; echo -n $'! U1 getvar "internal_wired.ip_timeout.value"\n'; sleep 5; } | telnet ${i} 9100
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your entry. To answer your question: I am attempting to check my list of networked devices to make sure their timeout values are set to 10. By default, many of them are set to 50. You're right, the `IP` variable needs to be an array at a later time, but I am using one IP address for now to better understand the logic first. I tried your code, and I received `"?"` as the output instead of `"10"`. Would you happen to know why it's doing this, instead of outputting the expected value?

Comment: I don't know anything about Zebra devices, so the command I put in might not be correct. I tested that code as an HTTP client and it worked well.
Verify that the `! U1 ...` command is correct and also try adjusting the sleep values.

Answer (score 0):

so here is what I suggest to use for the telnet part. Connect is a function being called later in a while loop, which will run over IPs ready from a file.

```
    Connect()
    {
    (
        sleep 10 # depending upon your network and device response, better to keep this first sleep value a little high

        echo "command 1"
        sleep 2
        echo "command 2"
       sleep 2
    ) | telnet $1 9100 | tee -a ${1}.log
    }

    while read -r IP 
    do 
       Connect $IP
    done < filewithIPs
```

Comment: Thank you for your entry. I may need to clarify that I am `SSH`-ing into a server local to these networked devices first, and while already in `SSH`, I am doing `telnet x.x.x.x 9100` which doesn't require any usernames or passwords to be passed.

Comment: So is it possible to place a script on that server so that you can run it from there? Or just try to add the `Connect` function in your original script, and then call it the point you need it. I've updated the function and removed username/password. This is a rather clean way to run commands on a remote device

Comment: Yes, from how our infrastructure is setup, we are encouraged to `SSH` into the servers local to the networked devices in that area first. I `scp` the `.sh` to the server first, then `SSH` in, then `bash myscript.sh` when I'm in.